Argument of the sum of two complex numbers $z_1,z_2$ such that $|\arg (z_i)|<\pi/4$
Let $z_1,z_2$ be complex numbers such that $|\arg (z_i)|<\pi/4$. By drawing these as vectors in the complex plane, it seems clear (at least intuitively) that the sum $z_1+z_2$ also satisfies $|\arg(z_1+z_2)|<\pi/4$. But I can't prove this rigorously as there is no formula for $\arg(z_1+z_2)$ in general. Is this statement true?
P.S. I am using the convention that $\arg \in (-\pi,\pi].$

Geometric approach solves it. What represents the sum?

@user376343 Do you mean the diagonal of the parallelogram?

@user376343 Actually I want an algebraic proof..

Once you have a geometric proof, it shouldn't be hard to turn it into an algebraic proof.

Let $z_1 = a+bi, z_2 = c + di$. Then, $\text{arg}(z_1) = \tan^{-1} (b/a)$ and similarly for $z_2$. See that $\tan(\theta)$ is an increasing function in $0<\theta < \pi/2$. Thus, $\tan^{-1}$ is also an increasing function.
$\text{arg}(z_1+z_2) = \tan^{-1}(\frac{b+d}{a+c})$. You can prove that $\frac{b+d}{a+c}$ is in between $\frac{b}{a}$ and $\frac{d}{c}$. Thus, as $\tan^{-1}$ is increasing, $\tan^{-1}(\frac{b+d}{a+c})$ is also between $\tan^{-1}(\frac{b}{a})$ and $\tan^{-1}(\frac{d}{c})$. Hence, $\text{arg}(z_1+z_2)$ is in between $\text{arg}(z_1)$, $\text{arg}(z_2)$. As both are $<\pi/4$, $\text{arg}(z_1+z_2)<\pi/4$
